# how to logout from rest api in yii2

Tags: php, json, rest, yii2

I m calling logout api in **yii2** framework using logout action

> url :http://localhost/mobile/public/api/v1/logout

Code:

```
public function actionLogout()
{
    $user_t = Yii::$app->user->logout();
    return $this->apiItem(array(),'Logout Successfully');
}
```

but after calling `logout api`

when after this  i calling `view profile api` it returns user data

```
public function actionViewprofile()
{
    $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;

    $profile_fetch = [
        'firstname'       => $user['member_fname'],
        'lastname'        => $user['member_lname'],
        'gender'          => $user['member_gender'],
        'dateofbirth'     => $user['member_dob']
    ];
    return $this->apiItem($profile_fetch);
}
```

where `apitem` is a function for json parameter format

```
 /**
 * Api Item response
 */
public function apiItem($data, $message = false,$flag = false )
{
    Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 200;
    return [
        'statusCode' => 200,
        'message' => $message ? $message : 'Data retrieval successful',
        'data' => $data,
        'flag' => $flag
    ];
}
```

Comment: do you have the authentication enabled for the action you are accessing after logout?

Comment: Yes how to clear auth token @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: I’d fetch token by client application and pass it to the server with each request (there’s no session concept in REST) as far as i know, or maybe i misunderstood what you are asking here

Comment: I pass auth token in header every time but in logout api i want to remove token from yii2 session

Comment: @Pritamkumar Please post your configuration `main.php` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the token from DB and clear the user session

```
 $userID = Yii::$app->session->get('userID');

 $userModel = User::find()->where(['id'=>$userID])->one();
   if(!empty($userModel))
   {
    $userModel->token=NULL;
    $userModel->save(false);
   }
   Yii::app()->user->logout(false);
```